# Is there a way to stop Fortran compiler from checking if negative arguments are passed to SQRT function?

Tags: fortran, automatic-differentiation

I am trying to use a third party automatic differentiation module, [ADF95](http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/summaries/ADVI_v1_0.html), which uses the expression `-sqrt(asin(-1.0_dpr))` to return a Not-a-Number (NaN) in specific cases, where `dpr` is defined using `integer, parameter :: dpr = KIND(1.D0)`.

Upon attempting to compile a simple test program which uses the `mod_adf95` module, with the command `gfortran mod_adf95.f90 main.f90 -o test.exe`, I get several errors, such as:

```
mod_adf95.f90:2511:36:

             f%deriv(1:lena) = -sqrt(asin(-1.0_dpr))*sign(1.0_dpr,a%value)
                                    1
Error: Argument of SQRT at (1) has a negative value
```

Clearly the square root of a negative `real` is undefined, and so I see why they would try to use this expression to get a NaN. So is there a way to tell the compiler to ignore these errors?

Comment: Please use the [tag:fortran] tag for all Fortran questions. Your question is not even Fortran 95 specific to add the version tag.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971836/having-parameter-constant-variable-with-nan-value-in-fortran/31972432 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744321/division-by-zero-doesnt-work-with-ieee-arithmetic-in-gfortran-5-4?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611059/positive-negative-infinity-constants-in-fortran?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It's also worth noting that this use of `sqrt` explicitly violates the requirements placed on a Fortran program by the Fortran standard.

Comment: I do not know of any such option for gfortran. It should not be that difficult to fix the code with IEEE intrinsics.

Comment: Modify the code to the `IEEE_ARITHMETIC` intrinsic module.  You can then use `IEEE_VALUE(X,IEEE_QUIET_NAN)` to obtain an NaN.  CHeck the standard, I may have the details slightly wrong here.

Comment: @evets the details are in the linked questions and answers, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/31972432/721644

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having parameter (constant) variable with NaN value in FORTRAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971836/having-parameter-constant-variable-with-nan-value-in-fortran)